# Can't run Grid Layout in 2.3 using support library

Tags: android

Hey Guys i'm trying to run my grid layout but it seems like it's giving an error log cat out put attached.
i imported and added library android-support-v7-gridlayout to build path and option order and export is marked. In xml i changed my tag  to  i do not understand what i am doing wrong pls. help.

```
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gridtest/com.example.gridtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at com.example.gridtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    ... 11 more
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    ... 22 more
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.gridlayout.R$dimen
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:270)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:289)
05-22 16:23:13.463: E/AndroidRuntime(15171):    ... 25 more
```

code XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="8"
        android:rowCount="8">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
          <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
            <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Jayant, what is your minSdkVersion? try setting it to 8 and let me know

Comment: it is allready 8<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you to add the imported library to the android panel in the settings, like this:

**-Right click on top of your Project

-Properties

-Android

-Library (Add)

-add the gridview project here

-now run your project!**

Also, what is your **minSdkVersion**? try setting it to 8 in the manifest, like this:

```
        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"  />
```